# How to make Ice cream less-creamy

Tags: ice-cream

Hey I'm making dole whip at home with my ice cream maker and when I made it, it was a bit too creamy and stretchy. Would there be anyway to make it taste less creamy? Would I have to reduce the ice cream mix or the water? I used 1 1/3 cups of mix and 2 cups of water. (Dole whip is supposed to be made without milk for those that don't know)

Comment: Welcome to the site @WhoThat. It's unusual for someone to think ice cream is too creamy,  usually the complaint is the opposite. Can you put in some more details? What do you mean by too creamy? Did you follow the directions on the mix? Is the mix an official "dole whip" mix or something you're trying to adjust? How long did you churn it?

Comment: And add the recipe and what you did with it.

Comment: Dole Whip is a specific product. It'd be nice if the question included an ingredient list, I suppose, but the question seems plenty well-defined to me.

Answer (score 4):

I never thought anyone would have me going out and looking up the ingredients in Dole Whip! Anyway, here goes.. Dole whip looks to be a mixture of sugar, coconut oil (the fat content), maltodextrin (for mouth feel, thickness), the fruit flavorings, and gum stabilizers, which will help keep the fat in suspension, preventing the cream from splitting as it melts.

If made according to instructions, it will be as creamy as *they* want it to be. The trouble is, if you make adjustments to make it as creamy as *you* want it to be, you may wind up compensating for the other ways in which you have thrown the flavor, feel, freezing point, stability. By the time you've done that, you may as well be starting from scratch.

So why not start from scratch? You'll find recipes out there for anything from sorbets, which have virtually no fat, and are not really creamy at all, through gelati, which are less cream-based, more fruit/nut based, to Cornish dairy, made with clotted cream!

Comment: Especially using more water could give nasty surprises (crystalline ice, which is rather unpleasant).